# Audio USB Interface and digital piano connected to one PC via USB parallely?

Tags: piano

I have already the Alesis io2 Express USB Audio Interface. I used it to connect my microphone and MIDI keyboard (the interface has midi in/out) to my computer. Now I want to buy a digital piano, which has only an USB port to connect it with the computer. Will both devices: the interface with the microphone, and the digital piano via USB work together /connected parallely?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  There can be problems connecting two audio interfaces to the same computer.  But the piano isn't an audio interface.  It uses USB as a MIDI connection - you're recording the keystrokes, not the sound.